# How can I merge independent json files which each contain dataframes?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a bunch of json files where each contains a dataframe of the same format:

e.g.

```
dir/1.json
dir/2.json
dir/3.json
...
```

And each dataframe looks like this:

```
text_input liked_vote disliked_vote

text        True         False
text        True         False
text        True         False
```

Each dataframe has either `liked_vote = True` or `disliked_vote=True` but not both! I.e. if one column is `True` then the other is `False`.

What I'm trying to do is recursively merge the json files until I get a dataframe which has `disliked_vote` as True, for example if `1.json` and `2.json` and `3.json` all have `liked_vote = True` and `4.json` has `disliked_vote=True` then I'd like to merge all the 4 json files into a single dataframe (e.g. `pd.concat[df1, df2, df3, df4]`), set `liked_vote = True` on the merged dataframe; and then delete the json files and save the merged files into `1.json`.

In summary I want to split on `disliked_vote=True` and re-merge dataframes/json files. I'm really not sure whatsoever how to go about doing this... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I'm right your trying to create one dataframe where everything is liked_vote = True.

```
from json import load
import pandas

# A list with paths to your json files
paths = ["/path/to/json/file.json", "/another/path/to/json/file.json"]

def read_json_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        file_data = load(f)
    return file_data

def concat_json(liked_data):
    # It seems like you already know how to do this, but tell me if I need to elaborate further. 
    pass

# Get all the json data in one list
json_data_liked = []
for path in paths:
    data = read_json_data(path)

    # Only append when liked_vote is True
    if data["liked_vote"] == True:
        json_data.append(data)

# Put all the dataframes from json_data_liked in one dataframe
one_dataframe = concat_json()
```

I hope this is what you ment.